# Create enumeration and use it in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to create some enumaration for `'a','b','test','123','blabla'` in following statement?

```
sum(case when col1 in ('a','b','test','123','blabla') then col2 end) as sum
```

I've tried to read it from `letters_table` like this:

```
sum(case when col1 in (select letter from letters_table) then col2 end) as sum
```

but it told me `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

and following is not working fine for me:

```
DECLARE @letters varchar(10)
select @letters = letter FROM letters_table
sum(case when col1 in (@letters) then col2 end) as sum
```

because when I print the `@letters`, there is just the last one `'blabla'`

Comment: Sum is a mathematical function and will not work on text. Perhaps you want to use a string one ... SQL server uses [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) I believe.  but may need to be used in concert with FOR XML Path to aggregate the rows.

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do. What are the col1 and col2 you're referring to? What sum are you trying to get?

Comment: @xQbert: is't just for this example, it could be any string, not just a, b, c, d but e.g. test, tree, heart, 123 etc.

Comment: @chipmunkofdoom2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286039/how-to-sum-listed-values-in-column

Comment: @gaffcz look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559551/sql-server-equivalent-of-wm-concat-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example using the subquery is probably the best - you just need to do the subquery and aggregation in two separate phases, like this:

```
select sum(x.col2) as sum
from (
    select case 
           when col1 in (select letter from letters_table) then col2 
           else 0 
           end as col2
    from YourTableName
) x
```

This should work as intended, and make the parser happy.

Answer (score 3):

If you have col1 (a text column) and col2 (a numeric column) in a table, say `myTable` and letter (a text column) in another table, say `letters_table`, then you can use a JOIN, as below:

```
SELECT 
    --mt.col1,        Include for totals by col1
    SUM(mt.col2)
FROM myTable mt
INNER JOIN letters_table lt
ON mt.col1 = lt.letter;
--    GROUP BY mt.col1    Include for totals by col1
--    ORDER BY mt.col1;   Include for totals by col1
```

Comment: this will return separate row for each word, which I believe is not what OP is asking for (based on his comments and [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286039/how-to-sum-listed-values-in-column))

Comment: @kristof I modified the query to get one total. This query should be faster as it uses a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

...or you could use a Common Table Expression, for example:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(1), col2 INT);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a', 1);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('c', 20);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('z', 3);
DECLARE @Letters TABLE (Letter VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @Letters VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO @Letters VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO @Letters VALUES ('c');
WITH PreQuery AS (
    SELECT
        col1,
        CASE WHEN l.Letter IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS GoodLetter,
        col2
    FROM
        @Test t
        LEFT JOIN @Letters l ON l.Letter = t.col1)
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN GoodLetter = 1 THEN col2 END) 
FROM 
    PreQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [solution posted by Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287958/3241) should do the trick, but there is no need to use cte
you can simply use the code below

```
select
   isnull(sum(mt.col2),0)
from 
  myTbl mt
  inner join lettersTbl lt
    on mt.col1 = lt.letter
```

If you want to include the letters involved in the results, you may use a variable. Looking at [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286039/how-to-sum-listed-values-in-column) here is a code with the same sample data that you have provided

```
declare @yourTbl table (col1 char(1), col2 int);
insert into @yourTbl values ('a', 10)
,('b', 5)
,('c', 15)
,('d', 2)
,('a', 3)
,('b', 6) 
,('c', 8) 
,('d', 10);

declare @lettersTbl table (letter char(1));
-- insert your letters here
insert into @lettersTbl values ('a'),('b')


-- only needed if you want to display the letters involved too
declare @checkedLetters as varchar(50)
select @checkedLetters = concat(@checkedletters,lt.letter)
from 
    @letterstbl lt

select
    @checkedletters 
   ,isnull(sum(mt.col2),0)
from 
    @yourtbl mt
    inner join @letterstbl lt
      on mt.col1 = lt.letter
```